# Beautiful Soup extracting all text between two tags, some of the text within the div is tagless

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I have been at this for a while now, I am using BeautifulSoup4 and I am attempting to get all the text between the first `<h3>` tag and the first `<h1>` tag. The problem is that .next and nextSibling all appear to skip tagless text.

This is what I am trying as of now

```
start = article_content(text="Description")[0]
end = soup.find_next(class_='title')
spell_description = ""
item = start.next
while item != end:
    try:
        new_text = item.extract()
        if new_text != '':
            strip_newline = str(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n\n', new_text))
            spell_description += strip_newline + '\n'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    item = item.next
```

This is the HTML

```
    <h3 class="framing">Description</h3>
      You detect magical auras. The amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject.
<br>
<br>
<i>1st Round</i>: Presence or absence of magical auras.
<br>
<br>
<i>2nd Round</i>: Number of different magical auras and the power of the most potent aura.
<br>
<br>
<i>3rd Round</i>: The strength and location of each aura. If the items or creatures bearing the auras are in line of sight, you can make Knowledge (arcana) skill checks to determine the school of magic involved in each. (Make one check per aura: DC 15 + spell level, or 15 + 1/2 caster level for a nonspell effect.) If the aura eminates from a magic item, you can attempt to identify its properties (see Spellcraft).
<br>
<br>
Magical areas, multiple types of magic, or strong local magical emanations may distort or conceal weaker auras.
<br>
<br>
<i>Aura Strength</i>: An aura's power depends on a spell's functioning spell level or an item's caster level; see the accompanying table. If an aura falls into more than one category, <i>detect magic</i> indicates the stronger of the two.
<br>
<br>
<i>Lingering Aura</i>: A magical aura lingers after its original source dissipates (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item). If detect magic is cast and directed at such a location, the spell indicates an aura strength of dim (even weaker than a faint aura). How long the aura lingers at this dim level depends on its original power:
<br>
<br>
      <table class="inner">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Original Strength</b></td>
            <td><b>Duration of Lingering Aura</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Faint</td>
            <td>1d6 rounds</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Moderate</td>
            <td>1d6 minutes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Strong</td>
            <td>1d6 x 10 minutes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Overwhelming</td>
            <td>1d6 days</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>Outsiders and elementals are not magical in themselves, but if they are summoned, the conjuration spell registers. Each round, you can turn to detect magic in a new area. The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it.<br><br><i>Detect magic</i> can be made permanent with a <i>permanency</i> spell.<br><br>
      </table>
      <h1 class="title"><img src="images\PathfinderSocietySymbol.gif" title="PFS Legal" style="margin:3px 3px 0px 3px;"> Detect Magic, Greater</h1>
```

output as of now

```
'You detect magical auras. The amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject.\n'
```

expected output

```
You detect magical auras. The amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject.

1st Round: Presence or absence of magical auras.


2nd Round: Number of different magical auras and the power of the most potent aura.


3rd Round: The strength and location of each aura. If the items or creatures bearing the auras are in line of sight, you can make Knowledge (arcana) skill checks to determine the school of magic involved in each. (Make one check per aura: DC 15 + spell level, or 15 + 1/2 caster level for a nonspell effect.) If the aura eminates from a magic item, you can attempt to identify its properties (see Spellcraft).

Magical areas, multiple types of magic, or strong local magical emanations may distort or conceal weaker auras.

Aura Strength: An aura's power depends on a spell's functioning spell level or an item's caster level; see the accompanying table. If an aura falls into more than one category, detect magic indicates the stronger of the two.

Lingering Aura: A magical aura lingers after its original source dissipates (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item). If detect magic is cast and directed at such a location, the spell indicates an aura strength of dim (even weaker than a faint aura). How long the aura lingers at this dim level depends on its original power:

Original Strength
Duration of Lingering Aura
Faint
1d6 rounds
Moderate
1d6 minutes
Strong
1d6 x 10 minutes
Overwhelming
1d6 days
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I added the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would use BeautifulSoup to find the first `h3` element then use `next_sibling()`
to find the next elements until `h1` is reached and print the NavigableStrings like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Comment

html = """
<html><p>stuff you dont want</p>
<h3 class="framing">Description</h3>
      You detect magical auras. The amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject.
<br>
<br>
<i>1st Round</i>: Presence or absence of magical auras.
<br>
<br>
<i>2nd Round</i>: Number of different magical auras and the power of the most potent aura.
<br>
<br>
<i>3rd Round</i>: The strength and location of each aura. If the items or creatures bearing the auras are in line of sight, you can make Knowledge (arcana) skill checks to determine the school of magic involved in each. (Make one check per aura: DC 15 + spell level, or 15 + 1/2 caster level for a nonspell effect.) If the aura eminates from a magic item, you can attempt to identify its properties (see Spellcraft).
<br>
<br>
Magical areas, multiple types of magic, or strong local magical emanations may distort or conceal weaker auras.
<br>
<br>
<i>Aura Strength</i>: An aura's power depends on a spell's functioning spell level or an item's caster level; see the accompanying table. If an aura falls into more than one category, <i>detect magic</i> indicates the stronger of the two.
<br>
<br>
<i>Lingering Aura</i>: A magical aura lingers after its original source dissipates (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item). If detect magic is cast and directed at such a location, the spell indicates an aura strength of dim (even weaker than a faint aura). How long the aura lingers at this dim level depends on its original power:
<br>
<br>
      <table class="inner">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Original Strength</b></td>
            <td><b>Duration of Lingering Aura</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Faint</td>
            <td>1d6 rounds</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Moderate</td>
            <td>1d6 minutes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Strong</td>
            <td>1d6 x 10 minutes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Overwhelming</td>
            <td>1d6 days</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>Outsiders and elementals are not magical in themselves, but if they are summoned, the conjuration spell registers. Each round, you can turn to detect magic in a new area. The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it.<br><br><i>Detect magic</i> can be made permanent with a <i>permanency</i> spell.<br><br>
      </table>
      <h1 class="title"><img src="images\PathfinderSocietySymbol.gif" title="PFS Legal" style="margin:3px 3px 0px 3px;"> Detect Magic, Greater</h1>
      <p>stuff you dont want</p></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
ret =[]
tag= soup.find('h3')
while True:
    if tag is None or tag.name == 'h1':
        break
    if isinstance(tag, NavigableString) and not isinstance(tag, Comment):
        ret.append(tag.strip())
    elif tag.text is not None:
        ret.append(tag.text.strip())
    tag = tag.next_sibling
print("\n".join(ret))
```

Outputs:

```
Description
You detect magical auras. The amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject.




1st Round
: Presence or absence of magical auras.




2nd Round
: Number of different magical auras and the power of the most potent aura.




3rd Round
: The strength and location of each aura. If the items or creatures bearing the auras are in line of sight, you can make Knowledge (arcana) skill checks to determine the school of magic involved in each. (Make one check per aura: DC 15 + spell level, or 15 + 1/2 caster level for a nonspell effect.) If the aura eminates from a magic item, you can attempt to identify its properties (see Spellcraft).



Magical areas, multiple types of magic, or strong local magical emanations may distort or conceal weaker auras.




Aura Strength
: An aura's power depends on a spell's functioning spell level or an item's caster level; see the accompanying table. If an aura falls into more than one category,
detect magic
indicates the stronger of the two.




Lingering Aura
: A magical aura lingers after its original source dissipates (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item). If detect magic is cast and directed at such a location, the spell indicates an aura strength of dim (even weaker than a faint aura). How long the aura lingers at this dim level depends on its original power:




Original Strength
Duration of Lingering Aura


Faint
1d6 rounds


Moderate
1d6 minutes


Strong
1d6 x 10 minutes


Overwhelming
1d6 days


Outsiders and elementals are not magical in themselves, but if they are summoned, the conjuration spell registers. Each round, you can turn to detect magic in a new area. The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it.


Detect magic
can be made permanent with a
permanency
spell.
```